# Map of string array and int array to 2D string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to figure out a way to return the map below as String[][]

```
private Map<String[], int[]> rows;
```

where  it originates from this class

```
public class Board {
   private Map<String[], int[]> rows;
   private String code;
   private int tries;

public Board(String code, int size) {
    this.tries = 0;
    this.code = code;
    this.rows = new HashMap<>();
}

public Map<String[], int[]> getRows() {
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you'd want to get for it? The question is somewhat unclear, at least to me.

Comment: Not really related to the question, but using arrays as Map keys doesn't feel right. Keys preferably shouldn't be mutable, or at least their `equals` and `hashcode` methods shouldn't be based on mutable data, otherwise Map can have problems with finding modified key. Maybe instead consider creating your own class which will hold as fields data from array (can't suggest anything more without knowing purpose of that map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Board {
   private Map<String, int[][]> rows;
   private String code;
   private int tries;

public Board(String code, int size) {
    this.code = code;
    this.tries = 0;
    this.rows = new HashMap<>(size);
}

public Map<String, int[][]> getRows(String code) {
    return rows !=null ? rows.get(code):null;
}

public void setRows(String code, int[][] data) {
    if(rows == null)
       rows = new HashMap<>();

    rows.put(code,data);
}
```